# How can I define event handlers in a Fabric.js subclass?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have the following subclass of `Rect` in Fabric.js. It adds an image to a Rect.

```
var IRect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
    type: 'iRect',
    initialize: function(options) {
        options || (options = { });
        this.callSuper('initialize', options);
    },

    fromObject: function (object, callback) {
        return new IRect(object);
    },

    toObject: function() {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {});
    },

    _render: function(ctx) {
        this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
        var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var img = document.getElementById('info');
        c.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, -this.width/2, -this.height/2);

    }
});
```

I want to define specific event handlers for `IRect`. For instance, when user clicks on an `IRect`, I want to `alert('hello')`. Where should I do this in my subclass ? How can I get a reference to the canvas while I am defining the subclass ?

Code and problem description can be found at: http://jsfiddle.net/czcsj2fw/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found a way to do it. I'm not sure its the correct way (I'm still very new to fabricjs!) but it does seem to work, at least for the trivial case. Basically the canvas isn't defined in initialise, but it is defined in _render, so if you set up your event handling code in there it should work :).

It looks like this :

```
_render: function(ctx) {
    this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
    // custom rendering code goes here ...

    this.canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
        console.log('mouse down ' + e);
    });
}
```

I updated your jsfiddle to demonstrate, it logs mouse clicks (mouse:down event) to the console (you get several events fired for one click so alert is pretty annoying - reckon you can stop it with cancelbubble or something but to keep it simple haven't bothered for the example) - http://jsfiddle.net/czcsj2fw/6/

HTH!

Comment: So that works for fabric.Rects , but it doesn't work for IText objects (this.canvas isn't set by the time _render is called so it seems) so I found an alternative, which seems to work for both :) fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/czcsj2fw/7/ but basically you do it in the added event handler instead

Answer (score 0):

It's better to define a handler on the first place, not each time `_render` called. This yields too many events and it would be a real performance issue on a production system. Here how I changed the above jsfiddle javascript code:

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------
// This is my subclass
var IRect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Rect, {
    type: 'iRect',
    initialize: function(options) {
        options || (options = { });
        this.callSuper('initialize', options);

        // var canvas = ??? how to get the canvas where this is displayed ?
        // canvas.on('mouse:up', function(){...}
    },

    fromObject: function (object, callback) {
        return new IRect(object);
    },

    toObject: function() {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {});
    },

    _render: function(ctx) {
        this.callSuper('_render', ctx);
        var img = document.getElementById('info');
        //
        // ctx is the 2d context, no need to get it again from canvas
        //
        ctx.drawImage(img, -this.width/2, -this.height/2);        
    }
});

// -----------------------------------------------------------
// This code will go to my HTML file

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');        

// Moved here to make it register once
canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
    console.log('mouse down ' + e);
});

var iRect = new IRect({
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    left: 100,
    top: 50,
    fill: '#888'
});
canvas.add(iRect);
canvas.renderAll();
```

And here it is forked from the previous: http://jsfiddle.net/gd06n7Lx/1/